# change wp-admin folder

Tags: wordpress, security, backend

I'm running some Wordpress websites and I have googled this several times without being able to find an concrete answer to my problem.

I have my sites protected with a login-lock plugin which locks an IP for a certain time if that IP tries to login with wrong credentials repeatedly.

So my problem is that I keep receiving alerts and alerts of IPs trying to login to my backend. I know I could turn those notifications off, but I would like to solve this correctly.

So I have seen some good WP sites where you can type the /wp-admin and nothing is shown, you get a 404 or you are redirected to homepage. I have also read here about a plugin called stealth login but plugin is no longer listed on wordpress site.

I have also saw some plugins that work with IPs and restrict the folder to certain IP but on my ISP I have a dynamic IP so if I have a new one I'd not be able to see the wp-admin folder.

I'd like to know if there is a standardized or a good way to fix that and hide the wp-admin directory to public.

Answer (score 2):

- The below code will prevent browser access to any file in these directories other than "a.b.c.d" which you should change to be your static IP address.

-

```
order deny,allow
allow from a.b.c.d # This is your static IP
deny from all
```

- OR restrict the directory with a password:

-

```
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
```

---

- Or you can protect it with a .htaccess file
  http://www.askapache.com/wordpress/htaccess-password-protect.html
- To answer you question as a apache URL layout configuration via mod_rewrite (the apache module that handles URL rewriting), this could be helpful:

  > RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /wp-admin/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I will check these options. As you can see on my post, the IP solution is not valid in my case because my ISP provides me with a dynamic IP, but I will check others and let you know.
Thanks!

Comment: I may not be correct, but I imagine your ip stays within a certain range. Lets say it's currently a.b.c.d - It will probably always be a.b.x.x or a.b.c.x - This being said you could set it to only allow a.b.x.x. It wouldn't entirely stop your issue with that method, but it would significantly reduce the appearances, as you will have a much smaller base of users that have that range of addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in my .htaccess file in the wp-admin folder:

```
order deny,allow
allow from 12.34.56.78 # My IP
deny from all
```

It will give a 404 error to anyone not on that IP address.

I also use the same for the wp-login.php page. Put this in your root .htaccess file:

```
<Files "wp-login.php">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 12.34.56.78
</Files>
```